# How to decode NaN value from JSON using Swift?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, nan, codable

**Null** values decoding works well with Codable protocol, but when I have JSON that has **NaN**, everything crashes, how do I solve this?

I have spent the last couple of days but did not find a solution.

Say, we have the following code:

```json
[{
   "id": 1
   "apples": 193,
   "oranges": NaN,
   "bananas": null,
   "pineapples": 405,
   "watermelons": 13
   "comment": "oranges and bananas have invalid values"
}]
```

And this struct:

```swift
struct Fruits: Codable, Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var apples: Int?
   var oranges: Int?
   var bananas: Int?
   var pineapples: Int?
   var watermelons: Int?
   var comment: String?
}
```

How to decode this with no crashes?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Please show the real JSON you get.

Comment: JSON is invalid that NaN is and integer as apples is integer so you can use decode if present to for decoding

Comment: You need to implement your custom `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` method

Answer (score 2):

since your data is not valid JSON due to `NaN` (`null` is ok), you could try this approach where the original data is made into valid json, works very well for me.

Note: you are also missing a comma after `id` and `watermelons`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear{
                let json = """
                [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "apples": 193,
                        "oranges": NaN,
                        "bananas": null,
                        "pineapples": 405,
                        "watermelons": 13,
                        "comment": "oranges and bananas have invalid values"
                    }
                ]
                """
                // simulated api data
                let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
                
                // convert to string
                let jsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                // convert back to data after replacements
                let newData = jsString.replacingOccurrences(of: "NaN", with: "null").data(using: .utf8)!
                
                do {
                    let fruits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Fruits].self, from: newData)
                    print("\n---> fruits: \(fruits)")
                } catch (let error) {
                    print("\n---> error: \(error)")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: alternative using `JSContext`:

```
import JavaScriptCore

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("using JSContext")
            .onAppear{
                let json = """
                [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "apples": 193,
                        "oranges": NaN,
                        "bananas": null,
                        "pineapples": 405,
                        "watermelons": 13,
                        "comment": "oranges and bananas have invalid values"
                    }
                ]
                """
                let fruits = decodeToFruits(json)
                print("\n---> fruits: \(fruits)")
            }
    }
    
    func decodeToFruits(_ badJson: String) -> [Fruits] {
        if let goodJson = JSContext().evaluateScript("JSON.stringify(\(badJson))"),
           let goodStr = goodJson.toString(),
           let data = goodStr.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONDecoder().decode([Fruits].self, from: data)
            } catch (let error) {
                print("\n---> error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you? Works very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the option of JSONDecoder to try decode not a number value. This option contains case of infinity too.

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy = .convertFromString(
    positiveInfinity: "Infinity",
    negativeInfinity: "-Infinity",
    nan: "NaN"
)
```

Comment: Note that NaN will need to be represented as a string eg: `{ "myFloat": "NaN" }`